# get stash restore error: pathspec with Powershell

Tags: git, powershell

As suggest here https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/106 I used

git restore 'stash@{0}' --

but still get

```
error: pathspec 'stash@{0}' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

So is there another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `git restore --source=stash@{0}` (which will require adding single quotes or whatever as usual for PowerShell).  That is, your mistake here is leaving out `--source=`.

Worth noting: `stash@{0}` and `stash` have exactly the same meaning, so there's no need to add the `@{0}` part.  If you leave it out, you won't run into PowerShell's special meaning for braces either, and won't need single quotes.  So

```
git restore --source=stash
```

is considerably easier.  The lack of a pathspec will make `git restore` fail, though, so you will also need to decide which file(s) to restore from source `stash`.